# Numeric String Never Equal in CF/Lucee cfquery

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, lucee

I have the following query:

```
<CFQUERY name="roster_unmatched_warehouse" datasource="admin_public">
SELECT RTRIM(B.EMPL_NBR) as EMP_ID
FROM ADMIN_DB.PERSON_TBL_WHSE B
WHERE B.BRGNG_UNIT_NBR=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#selectroster#">
</CFQUERY>
```

where selectroster is set to a 3 digit numeric string.

The issue that I'm running into is that no matter what, if I use a cfqueryparam, the equality is never true. One such example value that selectroster can be is '214', so I've also tried:

```
WHERE B.BRGNG_UNIT_NBR=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="214">
```

which unfortunately still does not ever match. The only success I've actually had was one of the following two lines:

```
WHERE B.BRGNG_UNIT_NBR="214"
- or -
WHERE B.BRGNG_UNIT_NBR='#selectroster#'
```

I have done a cfdump of the query with all 4 methods, and the output out of the query is identical, but the results are not. I have also played around with different sqltypes, removing now deprecated prefixes (cf, cf_sql_), to no avail. Database is Oracle, column is type char with data size of 4 (currently I'm wondering if that's the issue, since they're all actually 3 digit strings?)

Edit:
Adding a trim around the B.BRGNG_UNIT_NBR works, because the values are in fact stored in the database as '214 ', instead of '214'. Which makes the question, why did hard coding a 214 without a space work?

Comment: The column size is indeed the issue.  The database values have trailing spaces.  You could use a function on B.BRGNG_UNIT_NBR, but that would slow down your query.  Your choices are to change the datatype or to concatanate a space to your selectroster variable.

Comment: The first comment was on the original question.  As to why a hard coded value works without the trailing space, it's just one of those things.  Again, if this is a large table, adding a trim around the field name will make the query noticeably slower.  Another, less obvious approach would be to make the value attribute of your queryparam something like `left(selectroster & '   ', 4)`.  Note that there are three spaces between the quotes, just in case you get a string with only one or two digits.

Comment: Does the datatype need to be a `char`? Those have their purposes, but can easily cause headaches like this. Especially with Oracle.

Comment: Oracle can be weird in comparisons. As to why they equaled when you used `trim()`, that function returns a `varchar2` datatype, which would be what CF's `cf_sql_varchar` equates to.